# Do women have fetishes?

Tags: developmental-psychology, sexuality

As in title; is it possible/common for women to have fetishes?

It always seemed to me that fetishes are related to men only. Is it true?

Comment: Read 50 shades of gray. That will probably answer your question. Cannot imagine that there is any scientific research on this.

Comment: I am a woman (cisgender) and I have a fetish, so yes. It may be less common, but there are women with fetishes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a non-clinical sample in a study on paraphilic sexual interests, [Dawson et al. (2016)](http://sax.sagepub.com/content/early/2014/03/05/1079063214525645.full.pdf) report that

> Fisher’s exact test of proportions revealed that a significantly greater proportion of men reported arousal to activities related to voyeurism, fetishism, sadism, biastophilia, and urophilia compared with women (all ps < .05). A greater proportion of men were also more likely to endorse items related to frotteurism, hebephilia, and pedophilia compared with women (all ps > .05 and < .10). Similar proportions of men and women reported being aroused by activities involving exhibitionism, scatologia, transvestic fetishism, masochism, scatophilia, and zoophilia (all ps > .10). [Absolute numbers are reported in table 4 on page 13 of the PDF.]

*A fortiori* the answer is **yes**, women do »have fetishes«.

• Samantha J. Dawson/Brittany A. Bannerman/Martin L. Lalumière. 2016. Paraphilic Interests: An Examination of Sex Differences in a Nonclinical Sample. Sexual Abuse: A Journal of
Research and Treatment 28(1), pp. 20–45.

Comment: Oh wow, there is. Thumbs up.